# Difference between normal build and build with -Ob in GraalVM

Tags: java, maven, build, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

I'm new to `GraalVM` and I found that to build a Java application (spring-boot in my case) with maven in a `GraalVM` environment, the command is

```
mvn clean -Pnative native:compile
```

Now, at the end of the build logs, it says that there is an alternative way to build the same application in a faster way.

```
QBM:  Use the quick build mode ('-Ob') to speed up builds during development.
```

So, my question is what are the differences between normal build and quick build (`-Ob`)? Are there any demerits for using quick build? Definitely, the normal build is doing something that the quick build is not doing because of which it takes more time, right? Any ideas about which one to prefer and what time to prefer?

Answer (score 0):

`-Ob` turns off certain rounds of optimizations, thus making builds faster. It might make sense to use `-Ob` during development, and turn it off for production builds

Comment: Build always happen in developer's local, right? I can switch my repository for development to production but the build always happen in my local system. The other case is when using a CI/CD pipeline, in which case I'm unfamiliar how a build with GraalVM would work.